# Ansible non-root sudo user and "become" privilege escalation

Tags: ansible, sudo, privileges

I've set up a box with a user `david` who has sudo privileges. I can ssh into the box and perform sudo operations like `apt-get install`. When I try to do the same thing using Ansible's "become privilege escalation", I get a `permission denied` error. So a simple playbook might look like this:

`simple_playbook.yml:`

```
---
- name: Testing...
  hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: david
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Just want to install sqlite3 for example...
      apt: name=sqlite3 state=present
```

I run this playbook with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory simple_playbook.yml --ask-become-pass
```

This gives me a prompt for a password, which I give, and I get the following error (abbreviated):

```
fatal: [123.45.67.89]: FAILED! => {...
failed: E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: 
Permission denied)\nE: Unable to lock the administration directory
(/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?\n", ...}
```

Why am I getting permission denied?

**Additional information**

I'm running Ansible 2.1.1.0 and am targeting a Ubuntu 16.04 box. If I use `remote_user` and `sudo` options as per Ansible < v1.9, it works fine, like this:

`remote_user: david
sudo: yes`

**Update**

The local and remote usernames are the same. To get this working, I just needed to specify `become: yes` (see @techraf's answer):

Comment: What is the user name, the remote user that you using to perform the first ssh connection?

Comment: I think the become user is root, change root instead david, and it will works.

Comment: @helloV - I've also tried adding 'become true' to the task and the result is the same.

Comment: @Raul Hugo - the username is 'david' on both the remote and the local machine. If I remove 'become_user' it works and that is because it defaults to root (as per the docs). However I want to run it as 'david',, not as'root'.

Comment: @DavB see my updated answer.

Comment: "*However I want to run it as 'david',, not as'root'.*" - you cannot. Ansible uses APT package manager and it requires root permissions.

Comment: @techraf - the user 'david' on the remote box has sudo privileges. So, if I use `remote_user: david` and `sudo: yes` as per ansible <1.9, it works fine (with deprecation warnings). I've updated the question with this info. I thought it should work the same with with `become_user` and `become_method`.

Comment: Because `remote_user: david` has no effect. You already said "the username is 'david' on [ ] the remote machine". And `sudo` is an alias to `become`. You have wrong impression that something changed. The only problem in your playbook is `become_user: david`.

Comment: Well the problem was not ansible You need to understand better how sudo works xD

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Why am I getting permission denied?

Because APT **requires** root permissions (see the error: `are you root?`) and you are running the tasks as `david`.

Per these settings:

```
become: true
become_user: david
become_method: sudo
```

Ansible becomes `david` using `sudo` method. It basically runs its Python script with `sudo david` in front.

---

> the user 'david' on the remote box has sudo privileges.

It means `david` can execute commands (some or all) using `sudo`-executable to change the effective user for the child process (the command). If no username is given, this process runs as the `root` account.

Compare the results of these two commands:

```
$ sudo whoami
root
$ sudo david whoami
david
```

---

Back to the APT problem, you (from CLI) as well as Ansible (connecting with SSH using your account) need to run:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

not:

```
sudo david apt-get install sqlite3
```

which will fail with the very exact message Ansible displayed.

---

The following playbook will escalate by default to the root user:

```
---
- name: Testing...   
  hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
    - name: Just want to install sqlite3 for example...
      apt: name=sqlite3 state=present
```

Comment: Thanks @techraf for the explanation. If I use `remote_user: david` with `become: true`, it seems to works fine. Are these settings correct in this situation?

Comment: @DavB `remote_user` has no direct relation to the parameters starting with `become`. It is the `<user>` you use in the command the `ssh <user>@<server>`. In one of your comments you said you use the same user `david` both on the client and the server, hence you connect with `ssh <server>`. In this situation `remote_user: david` has **no effect**. You can include it, you can remove it. Nothing will change. The problem was with `become_user: david`. Only.

Comment: You would need `remote_user: david` **if** you were running Ansible on your (client) machine using an account named `davb` (or any other than `david`).

Comment: @DavB I already answered this in the first sentence and in bold font. If you run APT package manager using different user than root, you get an error message. This is how APT was written. Don't use it if you don't like it. You can install software without APT, though you will have to handle everything manually.

Comment: the user `david` has root privileges.

Comment: Have you read the answer which you are commenting? There is no such thing as "root privileges" in Unix. Either a process is running as root or as a different user.

Comment: sorry, finally the penny has dropped. Thanks a lot for your help (and patience)!

Comment: This is very unintuitive coming from normal userland, where `sudo` is for prefixing all management commants and `sudo su` or `su root` is for switching to root. Thanks for the explanation, I spent hours trying to find a reason for this, as ansible documentation doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 6):

`remote_user` is `david`. Call the script with `--ask-pass` and give password for `david`. If `david` doesn't have passwordless sudo, then you should also call it with `--ask-become-pass`.

```
- name: Testing...
  hosts: all
  remote_user: david
  become: true
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Just want to install sqlite3 for example...
      apt: name=sqlite3 state=present
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand what you mean. I already have `become: true` specified (and `become_method: sudo`). Could you clarify?

Comment: @helloV I also have similar question on ansible [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48724920/copy-files-to-remote-servers-but-in-a-directory-which-belongs-to-some-other-user) where I am not sure what wrong I am doing with either `become` or `become_user`. Wanted to see if you can help out?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

The issue is solved by using **root** and **--ask-become-pass --ask-pass** command together.

```
- name: Testing...
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  become_method: sudo

  tasks:
    - name: Just want to install sqlite3 for example...
      apt: name=sqlite3 state=present
```

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-become-pass --ask-pass
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using AWS ec2 ubuntu 2. The playbook was run with no options.