# copy files to remote servers but in a directory which belongs to some other user?

Tags: linux, ansible

I am working on an ansible playbook which copies my `tasks.tar.gz` file to remote servers and uncompress it into a particular directory on remote servers.

I am running my playbook on `machineA` as user `david` so I added public key of `david` user from `machineA` to all the remote servers `authorized_key` file so that I can ssh without typing my password because I want to run my ansible playbook passwordless.

```
---
- hosts: ALL
  serial: 3
  tasks:
      - name: copy and untar latest tasks.tar.gz file
        unarchive: src=tasks.tar.gz dest=/data/files/tasks/

      - name: sleep for few seconds
        pause: seconds=20
```

Now problem I am having is since this "/data/files/tasks/" directory on remote servers belongs to some other user `(goldy)` so it can't copy and uncompress `tasks.tar.gz` file because I am running my playbook as `david` user I guess.

```
ansible-playbook -e 'host_key_checking=False' test2.yml
```

I want to run my ansible playbook as user `david` passwordless but it should be able to copy files into all the remote servers in a directory which belongs to user goldy. I tried playing with `become` and `become_user` but it didn't worked for me. Is there anything else I need to do?

```
  - name: copy and untar latest tasks.tar.gz file
    unarchive: src=tasks.tar.gz dest=/data/files/tasks/
    become: true
    become_user: goldy
    become_method: sudo
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: changing ownership of ‘/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518323151.21-195554555527544/’: Operation not permitted\nchown: changing ownership of ‘/tmp/ansible-tmp-1518323151.21-195554555527544/stat.py’: Operation not permitted\n}).
```

Comment: Configure sudoers.

Comment: If I login on all the remove servers via putty then david user can sudo to goldy user if that's what you mean?

Comment: What does it mean "sudo to goldy user"?

Comment: I mean this "sudo su goldy". I still don't understand what I need to do when you say "configure sudoers"?

Comment: I even tried with `become_method: sudo` as well and still it fails. I updated my question with error message. I can't figure out what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: `sudo su goldy` is **not** "sudo to goldy user", but "run `su` command as root".　・　What I meant by "configure sudoers", is that you have to open books (or Google Search) and do your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you hint on having sudo configured for your connecting user `david`, the simplest thing you can do is use elevated permissions to copy the file and set its an ownership to `goldy` through `owner` parameter of the `unarchive` module:

```
- name: copy and untar latest tasks.tar.gz file
  unarchive:
    src: tasks.tar.gz
    dest: /data/files/tasks/
    owner: goldy
  become: true
```

---

For the question of how to configure sudoers to allow for executing commands on behalf of a user other than `root`, you need to learn how `sudo` and `sudoers` actually work (see [the manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.22/sudoers.man.pdf)).