# ansible behavior to specific sudo commands on managed nodes

Tags: ansible, sudo

Here to discuss the ansible behavior when user at managed nodes is given sudo privileges to specific commands.

I have sudo privileges on remote managed host [rm-host.company.com] to specific commands.  Two of them are:

```
   /bin/mkdir /opt/somedir/unit*
   /bin/chmod 2775 /opt/somedir/unit*
```

PS:  /opt/somedir at remote nodes exists already.

My ansible control machine version:

```
ansible 2.7.10
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Mar 26 2019, 22:13:06) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)]
```

YAML code fails when I use ansbile "file" module even though I have sudo privileges to chmod and mkdir as listed above.

```
   - name:  7|Ensure Directory - "/opt/somedir/{{ ENV_CHOSEN }}" Permissions are 2775

     become: yes
     become_method: sudo
     file: path="/opt/somedir/{{ ENV_CHOSEN }}" state=directory mode=2775

     when:
       - ansible_facts['os_family'] == "CentOS" or ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
       - ansible_distribution_version | int >= 6
       - http_dir_path.stat.exists == true
       - http_dir_path.stat.isdir == true
       - CreateWebAgentEnvDir is defined
       - CreateWebAgentEnvDir is succeeded

     register: ChangeDirPermission

   - debug:
       var: ChangeDirPermission
```

Runtime error:

```
TASK [7|Ensure Directory - "/opt/somedir/unitc" Permissions are 2775] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [rm-host.company.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "FIPS mode initialized\r\nShared connection to rm-host.company.com closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
        to retry, use: --limit @/u/joker/scripts/Ansible/playbooks/agent/plays/agent_Install.retry

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
rm-host.company.com     : ok=9    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

But succeeds when I use command module, like so:

```
  - name:  7|Ensure Directory - "/opt/somedir/{{ ENV_CHOSEN }}" Permissions are 2775

     command: sudo /bin/chmod 2775 "/opt/somedir/{{ ENV_CHOSEN }}"

     when:
       - ansible_facts['os_family'] == "CentOS" or ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
       - ansible_distribution_version | int >= 6
       - http_dir_path.stat.exists == true
       - http_dir_path.stat.isdir == true
       - CreateagentEnvDir is defined
       - CreateagentEnvDir is succeeded

     register: ChangeDirPermission

   - debug:
       var: ChangeDirPermission
```

Success Runtime debug output captured:

```
TASK [7|Ensure Directory - "/opt/somedir/unitc" Permissions are 2775] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo

changed: [rm-host.company.com]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [rm-host.company.com] => {
    "ChangeDirPermission": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "sudo",
            "/bin/chmod",
            "2775",
            "/opt/somedir/unitc"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.301570",
        "end": "2019-06-22 13:20:17.300266",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-06-22 13:20:16.998696",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": [],
        "warnings": [
            "Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Question**:

How can I make this work without using command module? I want to stick to ansible core modules using 'become', 'become_method' rather than running sudo in command module.

**Note**:

It works when sudo is enabled for ALL commands. But `[ user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL ]` cannot be given on remote host. Not allowed by company policy for the group I am in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *you can't*. The way ansible works is by executing python scripts in the remote host (except for the raw, command and shell modules). See [the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general).

The `file` module executes [this script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/file.py) with a long line of parameters. But ansible will first become the required user, in this case `root` by running `sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh` in the remote ssh session (please bear in mind that this command might be slightly different in your case).

Once the user logged remotely has become the root user, Ansible will upload and execute the `file.py` script.

It looks like in your case, you'll need to revert to use the raw, command or shell in the cases you need to run the privileged commands.

To understand this a bit better and see the detail and order of the commands being executed, run `ansible-playbook` with the parameter `-vvvv`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing the `become_method` and `become_user` off my playbook.

First, I specified the user in the inventory file using `ansible_user=your_user`. Then, I removed the `become_method` and `become_user` off my playbook leaving just `become=yes`

For more details about this answer, look on this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983674/ansible-non-root-sudo-user-and-become-privilege-escalation).