# Can't use Ansible become on a restricted sudoer user

Tags: shell, ansible, sudo

On my server, I have a sudoer user granted to only run chown in passwordless mode.

so, when I run

```
  sudo chown mytargetuser:mytargetgroup /my/path
```

it works. However when I try to do the same in an Ansible playbook :

```
  tasks:
  - name: change folder ownership
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    become_method: sudo
    file:
      path: "/my/path"
      owner: mytargetuser
      group: mytargetgroup
```

Ansible returns this error :

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

when using directly the shell module works too:

```
  - name: test via script
    shell : sudo chown mytargetuser:mytargetgroup /my/path
```

Is there an integrated way to include this behaviour in a playbook or should I remain with my last solution using the shell plugin ?

Regards,

Christophe

Comment: Please see this other answer: it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56717879/ansible-behavior-to-specific-sudo-commands-on-managed-nodes

Comment: Hi @Augusto, thanks for the link I haven't seen it.

Comment: please feel free to delete this question. Unfortunately, I cannot mark this one as a duplicate as the other answer is not accepted or upvoted ...

Comment: No luck, when I try to delete this question, I have the message : An error has occurred - please retry your request.

Answer (score 0):

Pass -K after playbook execution command for become password.

eg, > ansible-playbook sample.yml -K