# Ansible - run task with sudo with another user that is not the ssh logged user

Tags: ansible

Is it in Ansible possible to switch to another appuser and run a task with sudo with that user?

For instance I have the following users:

```
sshuser //ssh user that runs the ansible playbook
appuser //user that should run the task with sudo (with root permissions)
root
```

The task:

```
- name: Stop example service if running
    ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: example.service
    state: started
  become: true
  become_user: appuser
```

The appuser has the necessary sudo permissions in /etc/sudoers.

Edit:
With become_user as many of you suggested it does run without sudo that means with the permissions of appuser. But I want to run the command with appuser with sudo permissions.

Comment: [become_user:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#become-directives)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible non-root sudo user and "become" privilege escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983674/ansible-non-root-sudo-user-and-become-privilege-escalation)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to login as root and switch to appuser You can use become_user concept for your requirement.
Modify your ansible.cfg with the following

```
[privilege_escalation]
become = True
become_method = sudo
become_user = appuser
```

if you need to login as appuser and perform activities use the folowing code in ansible.cfg [defaults] section

```
remote_user = appuser
```

if you need to run a task with appuser use following code in ansible code.

```
- name: Stop example service if running
  ansible.builtin.systemd:
    name: example.service
    state: stopped
  become: true
  become_user: appuser
```